# USB plug/remove always wakes up *all* HDDs in powersave

Tags: ubuntu, usb, hard-drive

I got an anoying problem: Anytime I plug in or remove an USB-Stick from my Machine, Ubuntu 20.04 wakes up all HDDs in Standby. Those are even non-USB connected, internal HDDs.

I already [disabled the Tracker](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/07/how-to-completely-disable-tracker.html) but still the drives come back from sleep mode.

Any Help welcome!

Comment: don't shut your drives down, it does not help at. most, drives made to run, not to sleep while turned on

Comment: Why not. They're only needed few days in a month...